# Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO.get() not behaving as expected

Tags: ada

I'm about 5 hours into learning Ada. I made a simple program and I was putting different values into it and experienced behavior I can't explain.

My program works fine with normal inputs like km = 100, litres = 10, result = 10.0.

And obviously bad inputs work: km = "cat" result in "raised ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR"

But this combination of inputs has me baffled: km = 100..10. The program skips over the litres input and presents a result that works back to a litres value of 0.10. I was expecting a constraint error like when I entered 'cat'.

Can someone please explain this to me and how Ada programmers work around it so that 100..10 results in an error.

Here's my program:

```
--  This program takes km driven and litres consumed to calculate
--  fuel economy.

with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   package TIO renames Ada.Text_IO;
   package FIO renames Ada.Float_Text_IO;

   type Km is new Float range 0.01 .. 10_000.00;
   type Litres is new Float range 0.01 .. 10_000.00;

   package Km_IO is new TIO.Float_IO (Km);
   package Litres_IO is new TIO.Float_IO (Litres);

   Entered_Km : Km;
   Entered_Litres : Litres;

   function Fuel_Economy (
                          Entered_Km : in Km;
                          Entered_Litres : in Litres
                         ) return Float is
      --  returns fuel economy normalized to litres per 100 km
   begin
      return Float(Entered_Litres) / Float(Entered_Km) * 100.0;
   end Fuel_Economy;

begin
   TIO.Put_Line ("This program calculates fuel economy.");
   TIO.Put_Line ("Enter km:");
   Km_IO.Get (Entered_Km);
   TIO.Put_Line ("Enter litres:");
   Litres_IO.Get (Entered_Litres);
   TIO.Put ("Your fuel economy is ");
   FIO.Put (Item => Fuel_Economy (Entered_Km, Entered_Litres),
            Fore => 1,
            Aft => 2,
            Exp => 0
           );
   TIO.Put_Line (" litres per 100 km.");
end Main;
```

---

Exact output:

This program calculates fuel economy.

Enter km:

100..10

Enter litres:

Your fuel economy is 0.10 litres per 100 km.

[2018-05-06 14:08:16] process terminated successfully, elapsed time: 04.01s

---

I'm using GPS 2017 on windows 7.

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like 100. and .1 are parsed as valid floats, so it stops reading km at the second DP, leaving a perfectly valid .1 as the second argument. Amusing, but you'd have to read the ARM regarding ada. float_text_io carefully to find out if it was unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to discard the rest of the line after having read the (leading) number:

```
TIO.Put_Line ("Enter km:");
Km_IO.Get (Entered_Km);
TIO.Skip_Line;
```

Another, less straightforward, would be to check that there wasn’t anything left over:

```
TIO.Put_Line ("Enter km:");
Get_Km:
loop
   declare
      Input : constant String := TIO.Get_Line;
      Last : Natural;
   begin
      Km_IO.Get (From => Input, Item => Entered_Km, Last => Last);
      exit Get_Km when Input (Last + 1 .. Input'Length)
        = (Last + 1 .. Input'Length => ' ');
      TIO.Put_Line ("... just the number, please; '"
                      & Input (Last + 1 .. Input'Length)
                      & "' was left over");
   exception
      when others =>
         TIO.Put_Line ("... a number, please");
   end;
end loop Get_Km;
```

Comment: Why not simply check `End_Of_Line`?

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, you mean in the first option? I suppose I was thinking that trailing blanks would be OK.

Comment: Yes.  And you're right.  Not allowing trailing blanks may be a bit strict for some use cases.

Comment: Thanks. Please, correct me if I've misunderstood. When I called Get looking for a float with 100..45 "100." is a valid float so that gets bound to Entered_Km and the pointer is moved to the second decimal where the second call to get is also looking for a float and finds ".45" and binds that to Entered_Litres. Putting a Skip_Line call in between the calls to Get discards the remaining input string from my first call to Get so my next call to Get can retrieve new input from the user. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Blaine, that’s it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically experienced Ada users read the entire line into a String (using function Get_Line) and then extract the numeric value(s) from the String. Since programs like this typically loop until the user enters a valid value, reading into a String avoids a common problem with direct numeric I/O in which invalid input results in an infinite loop:

```
Get_Km : loop
   Handle_Invalid : begin
      Put_Line (Item => "Enter km");
      Get (Item => Entered_Km);

      exit Get_Km;
   exception -- Handle_Invalid
   when others =>
      Put_Line ("Invalid input");
   end Handle_Invalid;
end loop Get_Km;
```

The invalid input remains in the buffer and is repeatedly processed by Get.

Wright demonstrated a variation of this, but usually anything left on the line after the value(s) is discarded, so that input can be redirected from a file with trailing comments:

```
13.3 -- km traveled
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ada Language Reference Manual A.10.9(15-16)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-9.html#p15) your run-time library is behaving correctly, as these two formats are allowed syntax for `Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO.Get`:

- [+|–]numeral.[exponent]
- [+|–].numeral[exponent]